# Querying mongo db data from two schemas

Tags: json, mongodb, express, vue.js, mongoose

I have a MEVN application. I create two schemas for orders and items in mongoose. I want to combine it with item id. How can I do this?

this is orders schema

```
var Order = new Schema({
stakeholder:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
Items:[{
    item:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    quantity:Number,
    unitprice:Number
}],
total:Number,
final:Number
})
```

this is items schema

```
var Item = new Schema({
name:String,
description:String,
unit:String,
type:Schema.Types.ObjectId
})
```

I want to query for items like this pattern. i don't know if this is possible or not but i want to query like this pattern.

```
stakeholders,
items:[{itemid,name,description,quantity,unitprice}],
total,
final
```

Could you explain it with an example? It can be more helpful.

Comment: What you need is populate functionality available in mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via two approaches:

1. Mongoose Populate
2. MongoDB Aggregate Function

**First Approach**

More details on: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html
I would use this approach if i need the data in below format

```
[
{
  stakeholder,
  ...ordersColums,
  items: [
    {
      item: {...itemsColumns},
      quantity,
      unitprice
    }

  ]
}
]
```

For this can do below query:

```
 Order.find().populate(['items.item'])
```

You can also format the result if you like using a formatOrder function.

```
 Order.find().populate(['items.item'])
  .then(result => formatOrder)
```

**Second Approach**

Using aggregate functionality with following code:

```
const result = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Item",
        localField: "Items.item",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "item_info",
      }
    },
    {
     $unwind or $populate // depending on the format you need
    }

 ]);
```

If you like to format it into a specific format then can use the $unwind, $populate aggregators function and add them in the pipeline.

I Personally prefer find approach more than the aggregate pipeline approach.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use the aggregate operator.

Try this:

```
 const result = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Item", // collection to join
        localField: "Items.item", // field from the input documents
        foreignField: "_id", // field of the "from" collection
        as: "item_info", // output array field
      }
    }
 ]);
```

more in: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

you can use populate it's like `$lookup` in mongodb, for join collections.
for using populate you need `ref`

```
var Order = new Schema({
stakeholder:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
Items:[{
    item: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Item " },
    quantity:Number,
    unitprice:Number
}],
total:Number,
final:Number
})
```

with using populate join two collection based on _id of Item that inserted to the item field before;

```
await Order.find(filter).populate("Items.item")// path of field in schema
```